# how to record app's screen in android showing images in in custom slideshow?

Tags: android, audio, snapshot, screen-recording

Help me guys.. 
I want to records only my app's screen.My Apps screen contains images with slideshow and playing audio in background of slideshow. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Extend your view.

Override `onDraw()` method.

Create own canvas instance and call onDraw on your canvas.

Save canvas to Bitmap, save bitmap whatever you want or display.

Comment: Can you guide me through ?